# Damage Calculator

Tags: calculus

I am looming for a formula to work out damage per second. 
Stats are as follows:
Magazine Size: 6
Damage: 450
Reload: 13 Seconds
Rate of fire: 63.2 RPM or 1.05 RPS

So the forlmula goes like this:
$\frac{dmg \times ammo}{\frac{amm}{rps}+reload}=DPS$

But this weapon starts to reload from when you fire the first bullet so when firing the weapon until the mag is empty it gives tou more ammo that just six.

So anybody have a formula to work out the DPM or DPS taking the continuous reload in consideration?

Thank You.

Comment: Explain what you mean by reload as soon as the first bullet

Comment: If you mean that the magazine is reloaded exactly 13 seconds after the first bullet is fired

Comment: The weapon reloads a full clip in 13 Seconds but that means as soon as the first shot is fired it would be 6/13 right? So every 2 seconds about it reloaded a bullet. But putting that all in to formula. The weapon will fire not six shots but more. So I need to put that into a calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean reloading while firing, you have to remember, that reloading can't make the clip containing more ammo, than it's designed for.

therefore time to fire and reload the whole clip could be calculated using
$$t_c=\max\left\{\text{[time to fire the whole clip]},\text{[clip reload time]}\right\}$$

Of course time to fire the whole clip could be calculated using formula:
$$\text{[time to fire the whole clip]} = \frac{\text{[clip size]}}{\text{[RPS]}}$$

Finally we could obtain the formula as:
$$\text{[DPS]}=\frac{\text{[dmg]}\cdot\text{[clip size]}}{\max\left\{\frac{\text{[clip size]}}{\text{[RPS]}},\text{[clip reload time]}\right\}}$$

Comment: Ok. So this would include the reloading while it is firing?

Comment: Dpm? For reload while firing?

Comment: Yes - this formula is built for a machine, that is being reloaded while firing. I've also edited the answer - time to fire the whole clip was calculated in a wrong way.
$DPM=60DPS$.

Comment: Thanks jar. But to be honest i cant work the formula as shown maybe like in the way ill type it in say excel. For the not so xlever person to under stand. There is 3 formulas. Do I use all three.

Comment: Ok. Maybe im asking in the wrong way. Just as an example but keep the stats above in mind in my original question. The formula has to include a continuous / active relaod meaning.

Comment: e clipbexuase after all the shots have been fired and the trigger is get in after the 9 shots only every two seconds i will fire instead of one becuase no time is given for the whole clip to relaod of 5 shots.